# Read JSON file into Active Choices Plugin (Jenkins Pipeline)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have this config file which i want to use to create dynamic inputs for my Jenkins Pipeline. Reading the config inside the stages works well, but it does not work in the GroovyScript of the active choice plugin.

I have also tried to create the active choice parameters inside a stage, because reading the file works there. but somehow the array in the jenkins UI looks like this [Production, Test] and this does not work. If I change it manually to ["Production", "Test"] it works of course.

Any help would be much appreciated!

jenkins.appflow.json

```
{
  "environments": {
    "Production": [
      "saleschannel-1",
      "saleschannel-2",
      "saleschannel-3"
    ],
    "Test": ["saleschannel-1"]
  }
}
```

JenkinsFile

```
properties([
  parameters([
    [
      $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
      choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
      name: 'Environment',
      filterable: false,
      script: [
        $class: 'GroovyScript',
        script:[
          classpath: [],
          sandbox: true,
          // TODO this does not work
          script: '''
           def jenkinsAppflowConfig = readJSON file: 'jenkins.appflow.json'
           return jenkinsAppflowConfig.environments.keySet().toList()

          '''
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
      choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT',
      name: 'Saleschannels',
      referencedParameters: 'Environment',
      script: [
        $class: 'GroovyScript',
         script:[
          classpath: [],
          sandbox: true,
          // TODO get these options from the jenkins.appflow.json file
          script: '''
          if(Environment == 'Test'){
            return ['saleschannel-1']
          }
          if(Environment == 'Production'){
            return [
              "saleschannel-1",
              "saleschannel-2",
              "saleschannel-3"
            ]
          }
         
          '''
        ]
        
      ]
   ]
 ])
])

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('iOS & Android Pipeline') {
      steps {
       ....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First `readJSON` is a jenkins step **which is not available in the parameter's script block**.

You may try:

```
          // TODO this does not work
          script: '''
           import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
           def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
           def jenkinsAppflowConfig = slurper.parseText(new File('jenkins.appflow.json'))
           return jenkinsAppflowConfig.environments.keySet().toList()

          '''
```

NOTES:

1. The parameter's script is running always on your master / controller node
2. It runs before any clone / checkout so `jenkins.appflow.json` file **may not be there**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this and it does not work either. Do you maybe know, is there any way to debug this code blocks? Because like this I don't really know what the issue could be.

Comment: First, consider changing `sandbox` to false (if you use false you always need to approve scripts in `Manage Jenkins -> in process script approval`, if you see some error I suggest you to wrap the whole code with `try-catch(e)` including the imports and in the catch return [e.toString()]

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea. The problem is that it does not find the file. 
I have passed the repostiory checkout stage multiple times, so technically it should be there, but I guess the script does not have access to it this stage.
Also like you said, it would never have the most recent version of the config file, so it would useless even if it worked.
Thanks anyway!